# 301 Redirect rewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I have several redirects that are working for example these two:

```
    #Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    #fishing report
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^saintsimonsislandcharterfishing\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
    RewriteRule ^Fishing(?:[\ +]|%20)Report\.html$ http://www.charterfish.com/category/georgia-fishing-reports/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

    #shark and tarpon
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^saintsimonsislandcharterfishing\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
    RewriteRule ^shark(?:[\ +]|%20)and(?:[\ +]|%20)tarpon\.html$ http://www.charterfish.com/st-simons-shark-and-tarpon-fishing-charters/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

However this redirect is sending the original html page as the request to the new server:

```
    #about the captain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^saintsimonsislandcharterfishing\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
    RewriteRule ^About(?:[\ +]|%20)The(?:[\ +]|%20)Captain\.html$ http://www.charterfish.com/captain-tj-cheek/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

`http://saintsimonsislandcharterfishing.com/About%20The%20Captain.html`

is redirecting to:

`http://www.charterfish.com/About%20The%20Captain.html`

instead of

`http://www.charterfish.com/captain-tj-cheek/`

The regex appears correct, what am I missing?

Comment: That the entire rule is commented out?

Comment: I think that was me posting with a head ache... the commented rules were a test to see if the server was even reading the Rewrite. The actual .htaccess is not commented. I have adjusted the question to reflect the actual file.

Comment: Try using just this: `RewriteRule ^About.*The.*Captain\.html  http://www.charterfish.com/captain-tj-cheek/? [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Looks like some other rule is matching first and redirecting, the displayed rule can't really be doing that redirect at least.

Comment: using the simpler regex .* and cleared my cache all good now. Thanks a million :)